# Convergence in definite integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

When I evaluate
$\;\displaystyle \int_{-2.5}^{2.5} \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx,\;$ I get the answer as $-\dfrac{2}{2.5}.\;$ But wolfram says it the integral is divergent.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Your integrand is not bounded over the interval of integration. The Fundamental Theorem (which I assume you tried to use) does not apply here.

Comment: If you get a negative value for an integral of a positive function, something went wrong in between.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What happens at $x = 0 \in (-2.5, 2.5)\;?$

Here is a nice visual representation of the integral, compliments of Wolfram:

[image]

Representing the integral as "area", we see that it is unbound, i.e., the integral does not converge.

ADDED: You cannot utilize the "classical method" (i.e. the Fundamental Theorem) to evaluate an integral over a domain on which it is *not continuous*, as in this case where there exists a nonintegrable singularity at x=0 within the interval of integration.

Comment: I know that, at x=0, the value is $\infty$, but the classical method yields the result as $[\frac{-1}{x}]_{-2.5}^{2.5}$ = $\frac{-2}{2.5}$

Comment: You cannot utilize the "classical method" to evaluate an integral over a domain in which there exists a nonintegrable singularity, which in this case, exists at $x = 0$ within the interval of integration.

Comment: Careful with the classical method (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) In order to apply this theorem to a function (here $x \, \mapsto \, \frac{1}{x^{2}}$), you must first verify that the function satisfies the requirements of the theorem. Here, it requires that the function $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. Your function $x \, \mapsto \, \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ is not continuous on $[-2.5 , 2.5]$.

Comment: now I understand. Yes, I was wrong. I got the answer from [here][1]


  [1]: http://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter20/section04.html

Comment: @Amzoti Will do! Yes, my cats would like that...one would be perfectly content if she were glued to me. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is considered an improper integral as the function is not definite at $0$. The usual way to give it a value is to consider the limit for $\epsilon\to 0$ of $\int_{-2.5}^\epsilon \frac{1}{x^2}+\int^{2.5}_\epsilon \frac{1}{x^2}$, which diverges to infinity here. So it is not legitimate to just replace by a primitive as you did. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value for more details.